# Activated APK get error on Google Play: This application is available to over 0 devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I've uploaded my app yesterday and it populated in Google play market. However, I could not download it. My device says it is not compatible.

1. I checked the devices available and it was zero. I republished the app with removed all the permissions removed except for INTERNET. And It still says the app is not compatible with any devices.
2. I added the build path to all the jar files in the project.
3. I've set the screen

> ```
> supports-screens
>     android:smallScreens="false"
>     android:normalScreens="true"
>     android:largeScreens="true"    
>     android:anyDensity="true"
> ```

1. I've activated the apk each time and I continue to get "this application is available to over 0 devices"
2. This should alive in 2 hours https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1

Do yo have any suggestions on what to do to fix this error?

Here is the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.8" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <!-- 
GCM connects to Google Services. 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
-->

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.TabBarExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Tab1" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.ScheduleView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.PullToRefreshListView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Tutorial" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.About" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.ShowSettingsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.DemoActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.GCMAdapterUpdate"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlertSettings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventsView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.ConventionView" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.DataView" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.EventDetails"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateLocalDatabaseService"
            class="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateLocalDatabaseService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateLocalDatabaseService"
                    android:value="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateLocalDatabaseService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateAdapterService"
            class="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateAdapterService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateAdapterService"
                    android:value="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.UpdateAdapterService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.EventList.OneShotAlarmEvents" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlertView" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlertServiceDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlertsDetails"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.OneShotAlarm" >
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlertDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Notifications.NotesView" >
        </activity>
        <!--
          BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.

        -->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlarmsService"
            class="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlarmsService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlarmsService"
                    android:value="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlarmsService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.Alerts.AlarmsBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.AdapterUpdateReceiverActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        </activity>

        <!--
        <receiver android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.AdapterUpdateReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sugardefynery.animeconvention.scheduler1.AdapterUpdateReceiver.action" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


          Application-specific subclass of GCMBaseIntentService that will
          handle received messages.

          By default, it must be named .GCMIntentService, unless the
          application uses a custom BroadcastReceiver that redefines its name.

        -->
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="false"
   android:normalScreens="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"    


android:anyDensity="true"/> 

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

because of the recent update I need to import all my classes in to a new project and export. that fixed it.